# SQL. Сравнение полей, содержащих null

Tags: sql, null

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='man')
DROP DATABASE man
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='po')
DROP DATABASE po

CREATE TABLE man
    ([id] varchar(1), [razdel] varchar(2), [vidv] varchar (1), [sroks] varchar(10), [srokpo] varchar(10))
;
INSERT INTO man
    ([id], [razdel], [vidv], [sroks], [srokpo])
VALUES
    ('1', '80', '1', '01.02.2017', '30.04.2017'),
    ('1', '80', '2', '01.02.2017', '30.04.2017'),
    ('1', '16', '2', '01.02.2017', ''),
    ('1', '16', '2', '01.04.2017', ''),
    ('1', '80', '2', '01.05.2017', '31.07.2017'),
    ('1', '16', '2', '01.05.2017', '')
;

CREATE TABLE po
    ([id] varchar(1), [sroks] varchar(10), [srokpo] varchar(10), [summ] varchar(3), [izm] varchar(10))
;
INSERT INTO po
    ([id], [sroks], [srokpo], [summ], [izm])
VALUES
    ('1', '01.05.2017', '31.07.2017', '100', '01.01.2017'),
    ('1', '01.05.2017', '', '200', '01.01.2017')
;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно в зависимости от значения `razdel` выбирать сумму `summ` из таблицы `po`. Сначала из таблицы `man` выбираем нужную строку с искомым значением `razdel` и максимально поздней датой `sroks`. Потом нужно выбрать соответствующую ей строку из таблицы `po`. Соответствие проверяем по совпадению `id` и дат в `sroks` и `srokpo`, так как в таблице `po` нет поля `razdel`. Должно получиться: при `razdel=80 summ=100`, а при `razdel=16 summ=200`.
Проблема в том, что `sroks` могут быть одинаковыми, а `srokpo` может быть пустым для одного из разделов. Как сравнить `null` с `null`? База DB9.

Код:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.id, p.summ, p.sroks, p.srokpo, razdel 
FROM PO p

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, vidv, razdel, m1.sroks, m1.srokpo
  FROM man m1
  WHERE sroks=(
    SELECT max(r2.sroks) 
    FROM man m2 
    WHERE m2.id=m1.id and m2.vidv=m1.vidv
  ) 
) razd on razd.id=p.id

WHERE (p.id, p.izm, p.sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(izm), MAX(sroks) 
  FROM PO GROUP BY id) 
  and p.srokpo=razd.srokpo

) where id='1' and razdel='80'
```

выдает пустую строку при `razdel='16'`.

Если поменять `and p.srokpo=razd.srokpo` на `and p.srokpo=razd.srokpo or p.srokpo is null` то выдает обе строки при `razdel='80'`

Comment: У вас проблема с приоритетами операций, OR вечно все портит, потому что когда вы его добавляете получается `(все остальные уловия с AND) OR условие`. Поэтому поставьте скобки `прочие условия AND (p.srokpo=razd.srokpo or p.srokpo is null)` или может короче будет `coalesce(razd.srokpo,'01.01.3000')=coalesce(p.srokpo,'01.01.3000')`. Лично я вообще не люблю NULL при работе с интервалами дат и предпочитаю дату окончания ставить в БД в 3000 год для обозначения еще не окончившегося промежутка

Comment: В смысле вот так?
`WHERE
(p.id, p.izm, p.sroks) IN (SELECT id, MAX(izm), MAX(sroks) FROM VPL.PODMO GROUP BY id)
and (p.srokpo=razd.srokpo or p.srokpo is null)`
Что то не получается. Так при `razdel='16'` тоже ничего не вибирает. При `razdel='80'` выбирает правильную строку.

Comment: Выполните запрос частями, посмотрите какая часть какие данные дает и какие из условий соединения будут или не будут срабатывать. думаю там что то из за того, что в первой таблице NULL, хотя условие по второй таблице `p.srokpo is null` должно было бы перекрыть эту ситуацию, но видимо что то идет не так и нужно вообще что то вроде `(p.srokpo=razd.srokpo or (p.srokpo is null and razd.srokpo is null))` так что с coalesce возможно уже проще ...